# Bouncy Castle pem Reader Throws exception When Reading Public Key

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I am trying to encrypt a message in C# (in Unity) using a public key. To do this I am using the Bouncy Castle library. I get an error when trying to read the public key using the bouncy castle pem reader. I took this code from [here](https://gist.github.com/dziwoki/cc41b523c2bd43ee646b957f0aa91943). The specific error I get is:

`ArgumentException: illegal object in GetInstance: Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Dersequence`

Here is the code:

```
     static string encrypt(string plainText) {
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        PemReader pr = new PemReader(
            new StringReader(m_publicKey)
        );
        RsaKeyParameters keys = (RsaKeyParameters)pr.ReadObject();

        OaepEncoding eng = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine());
        eng.Init(true, keys);

        int length = plainTextBytes.Length;
        int blockSize = eng.GetInputBlockSize();
        List<byte> cipherTextBytes = new List<byte>();
        for (int chunkPosition = 0;
            chunkPosition < length;
            chunkPosition += blockSize)
        {
            int chunkSize = Math.Min(blockSize, length - chunkPosition);
            cipherTextBytes.AddRange(eng.ProcessBlock(
                plainTextBytes, chunkPosition, chunkSize
            ));
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes.ToArray());
    }
```

The error occurs when instantiating the pem reader. there is a slight difference in my code and the example code linked (I use a StringReader rather than reading from a file), but I get the same error if I read from a file. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I hope this helps anyone else who makes this silly mistake. My public key was of the format:

```
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Apparently this format is not accepted.

after removing the "RSA" from the header and footer, it was able to load the public key.

EDIT: If helpful for anyone, The key was generated by a go's crypto/rsa package. (GenerateKey function)

Comment: Changing the header does not in any way change the format of the key.

Comment: I mean, tell that to bouncy castle. When I removed "RSA", it worked. When "RSA" was still in the header it didn't work.

Comment: You never explained where the key came from and how it came to be in that format.

Comment: Fair point, and I'll edit for clarity, but this still means the header format matters for bouncy castle.

Comment: Yes, because Bouncycastle doesn't try all possible formats until it finds one that works, it uses the header as a hint to the format. If you put the *wrong* header on, then Bouncycastle will try to parse it according to that incorrect hint and will fail. `BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY` implies a pkcs#1 header specific to RSA. `BEGIN PUBLIC KEY` implies a RFC 5280 SubjectPublicKeyInfo header that works for other type of public keys as well as RSA.

Comment: then why is the go security package able to load it if it has the incorrect header for the specified format? Also, how did it wind up with that header if it was generated by the rsa package in the go library?

Comment: Show me the go code that generated it, then I'll believe it. In my opinion parsing of crypto values should be very strict, so trying multiple formats until one seems to work is a poor design choice. I don't know of any specific vulnerabilities it introduces but it's the kind of thing smart hackers tend to exploit.

Comment: It is literally just `rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)` which is a call to a function in crypto/rsa

Comment: Wait! actually, in saving the code there is this function:
    
    `func PublicKeyToBytes(pub *rsa.PublicKey) []byte {
 pubASN1, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(pub)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, err.Error())
 }

 pubBytes := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{
  Type:  "RSA PUBLIC KEY",
  Bytes: pubASN1,
 })

 return pubBytes
}` sorry about the format. not sure how to format  code in comments